# Blacked out Memory Glasses

Tags: physical-resources

Does anyone know where I might be able to get blacked out glasses? This is what they use in the memory competitions, and it is helpful for memorizing language vocabulary.

[image: memory competition glasses]

They block out the peripheral vision so you can avoid distractions in public places like coffee shops. I will drill holes in the center so I can see through a narrow view only.

I've been perusing avidly online on Amazon and Google shopping but haven't found anything. Can someone point me to where I might obtain blacked out eyewear?

Answer (score 2):

Those are just regular safety goggles [spray-painted black and drilled with holes](https://archive.nytimes.com/www.nytimes.com/interactive/2011/02/20/magazine/mind-secrets.html?_r=0).